# Mongoose "VersionError" when saving an array objects to MongoDB database

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

as the title says, I am having an issue saving an array of objects to the database.

I am being sent an array of objects from the client.

I have 3 arrays, all containing objects
- an array containing the user's current favourite stations
- an array containing stations that the user would like to remove
- and an array containing stations the user would like to add to their favourites

I then perform some logic that will remove the stations the user wants to remove from the user's favourite stations. I then concatenate the updated favourites with the stations the user wants to add. I would like to replace the old favourites with the updated array of objects in the database.

The problem with this, is that it returns this error, and it wont update the database. I can't seem to find a solution to fix it.

```
  message: 'No matching document found for id "5eada425ad35cdeac7c987f2" version 0 modifiedPaths "favouriteStations"',
  name: 'VersionError',
  version: 0,
  modifiedPaths: [ 'favouriteStations' ]
}
```

Here is the post request logic that I am using at the moment

```
router.post("/favourites", (req, res) => {
  console.log("UPDATING USER FAVE STATIONS");
  const { id, removedStations, selectedStations, favouriteStations } = req.body;

  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    console.log("There are validation errors");
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  } else {
    UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { findOneAndUpdate: false })
      .then((user, err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("ERROR", err);
          res.sendStatus(500);
        } else {
          const removed = favouriteStations.filter(
            (fave) =>
              !removedStations.some((rem) => rem.crs_code === fave.crs_code)
          );

          const final = removed.concat(selectedStations);

          user.favouriteStations = final;

          user.save((err, user) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log("ERROR", err);
              res.sendStatus(500);
            } else {
              console.log(("UPDATED", user));
              res.sendStatus(200);
            }
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: what version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: Hey, I am using MongoDB Atlas with Version 4.2

Comment: In 4.2 you can use the pipeline form of update with `$setUnion` and `$setDifference` to do that in one round trip to the database.